# Batchwise evaluation of piecewise polynomials on GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu, batch-processing, interpolation, spline

I am trying to evaluate points in a large piecewise polynomial, which is obtained from a cubic-spline. I am attempting to do this on a GPU and I am running into memory limitations.

As such, I would like to evaluate a piecewise polynomial in batches.

Original code:

```
Y = some_matrix_of_data_values ;
X = some_vector_of_data_sites ;
pp = spline(X, Y) ; % get the piecewise polynomial form of the cubic spline. The resulting structure is very large.

for t = 1: big_number
    hcurrent = ppval(pp,t); %evaluate the piecewise polynomial at t
    y(t) = sum(x(t:t+M-1).*hcurrent,1) ; % do some operation of the interpolated value. Most likely not relevant to this question.
end
```

vectorised, hopefully on the way to GPU batch processing:

```
Y = some_matrix_of_data_values ;
X = some_vector_of_data_sites ;
pp = spline(X, Y) ; % get the piecewise polynomial form of the cubic spline. Resulting structure is very large.
batchSize = 1024 ;

for tt = 1: batchSize: big_number
    if tt > big_number - batchSize % snatch up any remaining values at the end of the loop, and calculate those as well
        batchSize = big_number - tt ;
    end            
    hcurrent =  ppval(pp ,(tt:tt+batchSize-1) ) ;  %evaluate pp at a couple of data sites     

    ind = bsxfun(@plus, 1:M, (tt-1:1:tt+batchSize-2).')) ; %make an index matrix to help with next calculation. Most likely not relevant to this question.
    y(tt:tt+batchSize-1) = sum( x(ind).*hcurrent' , 2 ) ; % do some calculation, but now we have done it in batches!
end
```

In the revised code, the piecewise polynomial is evaluated at multiple data sites, so we are at least on our way there. The piecewise polynomial `pp` is too large to store on the GPU, is there a way to break it up for batch processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helpful thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498490/parallelization-of-piecewise-polynomial-evaluation), which instead talks about the Parallelization of Piecewise Polynomial Evaluation. This solution can be ported to GPU for batch processing.