# Parallelization of Piecewise Polynomial Evaluation

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization, spline

I am trying to evaluate points in a large piecewise polynomial, which is obtained from a cubic-spline. This takes a long time to do and I would like to speed it up.

As such, I would like to evaluate a points on a piecewise polynomial with parallel processes, rather than sequentially.

Code:

```
z = zeros(1e6, 1) ;    % preallocate some memory for speed
Y = rand(11220,161) ;  %some data, rand for generating a working example
X = 0 : 0.0125 : 2 ;   % vector of data sites
pp = spline(X, Y) ;    % get the piecewise polynomial form of the cubic spline.
```

The resulting structure is large.

```
for t = 1 : 1e6  % big number
    hcurrent = ppval(pp,t); %evaluate the piecewise polynomial at t
    z(t) = sum(x(t:t+M-1).*hcurrent,1) ; % do some operation of the interpolated value. Most likely not relevant to this question.
end
```

Unfortunately, with matrix form and using:

```
hcurrent = flipud(ppval(pp, 1: 1e6 ))
```

requires too much memory to process, so cannot be done. Is there a way that I can batch process this code to speed it up?

Comment: You can start by pre-allocating `y`. It would be helpful to provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with runnable code so we can be sure we're looking at the same problem. How big is `big_number`? What is `M`  and is `x` the same as `X`?

Comment: Thank you, I have clarified further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scalar second arguments, as in your example, you're dealing with two issues. First, there's a good amount of function call overhead and redundant computation (e.g., `unmkpp(pp)` is called every loop iteration). Second, [`ppval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ppval.html) is written to be general so it's not fully vectorized and does a lot of things that aren't necessary in your case.

Below is vectorized code code that take advantage of some of the structure of your problem (e.g., `t` is an integer greater than 0), avoids function call overhead, move some calculations outside of your main `for` loop (at the cost of a bit of extra memory), and gets rid of a `for` loop inside of `ppval`:

```
n = 1e6;
z = zeros(n,1);
X = 0:0.0125:2;
Y = rand(11220,numel(X));
pp = spline(X,Y);

[b,c,l,k,dd] = unmkpp(pp);
T = 1:n;
idx = discretize(T,[-Inf b(2:l) Inf]); % Or: [~,idx] = histc(T,[-Inf b(2:l) Inf]);
x = bsxfun(@power,T-b(idx),(k-1:-1:0).').';

idx = dd*idx;
d = 1-dd:0;
for t = T
    hcurrent = sum(bsxfun(@times,c(idx(t)+d,:),x(t,:)),2);
    z(t) = ...;
end
```

The resultant code takes ~34% of the time of your example for `n=1e6`. Note that because of the vectorization, calculations are performed in a different order. This will result in slight differences between outputs from `ppval` and my optimized version due to the nature of floating point math. Any differences should be on the order of a few times `eps(hcurrent)`. You can still try using `parfor` to further speed up the calculation (with four already running workers, my system took just 12% of your code's original time).

I consider the above a proof of concept. I may have over-optmized the code above if your example doesn't correspond well to your actual code and data. In that case, I suggest creating your own optimized version. You can start by looking at the code for `ppval` by typing `edit ppval` in your Command Window. You may be able to implement further optimizations by looking at the structure of your problem and what you ultimately want in your `z` vector.

Internally, `ppval` still uses [`histc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), which has been deprecated. My code above uses [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) to perform the same task, [as suggested by the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html).

Comment: Thank you for this answer and advice. Your suggestions of looking at the ppval function, and  re-implementing it out of the for loop to reduce redundant computation and function overhead is particularly helpful. I am having trouble seeing how line: 'x = bsxfun(@power,T-b(idx),(k-1:-1:0).').';' relates in the ppval function, but once I have worked it out I will post my completed, optimized code as well. Thank you once again for your advice.

Comment: Ah, the x = bsxfun(@power,T-b(idx),(k-1:-1:0).').'; line is a stroke of genius. Thank you again, I have managed to process this data in only 20% of the time, without the use of parfor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parfor` command for parallel loops. see [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html), also precompute z vector as `z(j) = x(j:j+M-1)` and hcurrent in `parfor` for speed up.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is true that using parfor will help with a speed up. Since the for loop is currently very inefficient, the parfor loop will also however (albeit less so). As a result, this will not help my particular problem enough.

Comment: Also consider data splitting and exclusive multi-threading in matlab with Java to parallelize. Instead of splines you can use slope of moving window to calculate ppval, that would be very fast.

Comment: Great recommendation! Currently working on datasplitting and offloading to GPU for processing, but so far have not go any major speed improvements, due to large amounts of data copying on/off the GPU. I suspect that moving window ppval calculations might be the solution, as you have suggested.

Comment: If you like, give me some points on answer :). There is something called MEX functions in MATLAB that would be further fast as in C/C++

Answer (score 0):

The Spline Parameters estimation can be written in Matrix form.

Once you write it in Matrix form and solve it you can use the Model Matrix to evaluate the Spline on all data point using Matrix Multiplication which is probably the most tuned operation in MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately this requires to much memory. I have clarified in the original post. I feel like batch processing may be the solution.